# This connection is not private message on iOS

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I have searched something on google with my iPhone (Safari web browser).

I have clicked on a website in google results. It seems the https certificate of this website has expired. Safari shows me a warning page with "This connection is not private".
That does not really matter to me so i'have clicked on "visit this website" anyway.

There is something very strange and i am very upset about it. I saw a quick redirection with an url starting with "file://". This happens during 1 second so i did not see anything else and i have been redirected on the website then.

As anyone ever seen this "file://..." redirection ? Could it be an exploit ?

I have tried to visit the site again and i did not have the warning message again. Maybe safari has memorized my action on this website. Is it possible to reset this ? (i have tried to reset history and safari settings but it does not displays me the message again)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour so you shouldn't worry about it. The page with `file` protocol is located at `file:///System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SafariShared.framework/CertificateWarning.html` and is just SSL warning page you've seen. This URL shows for a moment before Safari will redirect you from warning page to the target.

[image: Screenshot of Safari]

You can try it yourself by visiting [badssl.com](https://badssl.com). If you choose to visit the page with bad certificate, Safari will remember it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Safari automatically redirects you to a system file showing a warning when it's potentially insecure. The `file` URI means that the site is local. There is nothing to worry about since Safari's automatic warning page *is* local. However, the new and current path to the warning no longer is `file:///System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SafariShared.framework/CertificateWarning.html` but instead `file:///system/library/privateframeworks/safarishared.framework/certificatewarningfall2023.html`